# neo4j can't 'match' the way i want to

Tags: neo4j, match, cypher

I need to do a match statement but I just can't seem to get the results the way i want to.

I have a node -Campaign. The campaign is connected to multiple pictures nodes. Each picture has a photographer node ,a location node, a Facebook picture representative node. To the facebook picture node has a connected node of a Facebook album node.

I want to create a match statement that will give me this hierarchy .

campaign with pictures inside of it and inside each picture all the nodes that connected to it like I said.

```
match (campaign:Campaign)<-[:TAKEN_IN]-(picture:Picture) where id(campaign) =108
 with campaign,collect(picture) as pictures  
 optional match picture -[r *1..3]->(s) 
 with campaign,pictures,collect(s) as nodess 
 return  campaign,pictures,nodess
```

I tried something like that, but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can't match on a picture if it already has been *aggregated* into a list.

Remove the first with which does the aggregation, and for the `optional match` make sure to spell out the things you want to match (probably with listing the 3 different rel-types).

Not sure what the 3-step variable length paths gives you from your description.